# Clear password text field after user signs in

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase-authentication, uitextfield

If a user signs in, then signs back out immediately after, the password text field is still populated with their password. But for security, I'd like to make them have to re-type their password. I'm using firebase authentication

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTF.text!, password: passwordTF.text!) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            print("Successful Login!")
            self.passwordTF.text = nil
        } else {
            print("Error logging in: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

This is what I have so far, which empties out the text field, but there is one problem. There is a function that checks if the username OR password text field is empty. If one of them is, it disables the sign in button. With this method of emptying the textfield that functionality of disabling the sign in button doesn't work anymore. After the user signs out the password text field is empty, but the login button is enabled, which it shouldn't be.

```
@objc func editingChanged() {
    if emailTF.text!.isEmpty || passwordTF.text!.isEmpty {
        loginButton.isEnabled = false
        loginButton.alpha = 0.5
        //print("Email and password fields NOT FILLED in")
    } else {
        loginButton.alpha = 1
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
        //print("Email and password field FILLED in")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
self.passwordTF.text = ""
```

It will always pay off to avoid force unwrapping variables in your code like so:

```
@objc func editingChanged() {
    guard let email = emailTF.text, let password = passwordTF.text else {
        return
    }
    if email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
    //rest of your code
}
```

and make sure you call `editingChanged()` in `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: The checking of the optional definitely makes sense, but when I am signed out and returned to the login screen the login button is still enabled, even though the password field is empty. It's like the view doesn't reload for some reason once it's brought back to the top of the stack. Any ideas?

Comment: @cabyambo are you sure you're calling `editingChanged()` when the view loads or appears? You'll have to call it whenever you go back to that VC

Comment: Thanks! I was only calling it when the text fields were being edited, but when I call it in `viewDidAppear()` it works as expected.